# Filebeat unable send logs to logzio via haproxy

Tags: haproxy, filebeat, logz.io

Following is the output snippet from my filebeat.yml

```
output:
  logstash:
    hosts: ['192.168.200.38:5015']
```

where 192.168.200.38:5015 is a haproxy server listening in tcp mode.

Following is my haproxy configuration:

```
global
  daemon
  maxconn 256

defaults
  mode tcp
  timeout connect 5000ms
  timeout client 50000ms
  timeout server 50000ms
  timeout tunnel 1h

listen stats
  bind 0.0.0.0:9999
  stats enable
  stats hide-version
  stats uri /stats

frontend proxy_in
  bind 0.0.0.0:5015

backend proxies_out
  balance roundrobin
  mode tcp
  server ip-1 listener.logz.io:5015
```

Using the above configuration I get the following error:

```
Jul 02 14:32:46 cust1-bast-linux-0 filebeat[83565]: 2019-07-02T14:32:46.560Z DEBUG [logstash] logstash/async.go:111 connect
Jul 02 14:32:46 cust1-bast-linux-0 filebeat[83565]: 2019-07-02T14:32:46.562Z INFO pipeline/output.go:105 Connection to backoff(async(tcp://192.168.200.38:5015)) established
Jul 02 14:32:46 cust1-bast-linux-0 filebeat[83565]: 2019-07-02T14:32:46.563Z DEBUG [logstash] logstash/async.go:159 1 events out of 1 events sent to logstash host 192.168.200.38:5015. Continue sending
Jul 02 14:32:46 cust1-bast-linux-0 filebeat[83565]: 2019-07-02T14:32:46.564Z DEBUG [transport] transport/client.go:218 handle error: EOF
Jul 02 14:32:46 cust1-bast-linux-0 filebeat[83565]: 2019-07-02T14:32:46.564Z DEBUG [transport] transport/client.go:131 closing
Jul 02 14:32:46 cust1-bast-linux-0 filebeat[83565]: 2019-07-02T14:32:46.564Z ERROR logstash/async.go:256 Failed to publish events caused by: EOF
Jul 02 14:32:46 cust1-bast-linux-0 filebeat[83565]: 2019-07-02T14:32:46.565Z DEBUG [logstash] logstash/async.go:159 1 events out of 1 events sent to logstash host 192.168.200.38:5015. Continue sending
Jul 02 14:32:46 cust1-bast-linux-0 filebeat[83565]: 2019-07-02T14:32:46.565Z DEBUG [logstash] logstash/async.go:116 close connection
Jul 02 14:32:46 cust1-bast-linux-0 filebeat[83565]: 2019-07-02T14:32:46.565Z ERROR logstash/async.go:256 Failed to publish events caused by: client is not connected
Jul 02 14:32:46 cust1-bast-linux-0 filebeat[83565]: 2019-07-02T14:32:46.565Z DEBUG [logstash] logstash/async.go:116 close connection
```

I am using haproxy server as a proxy server here. Earlier I had squid proxy(http) which will not work with filebeat. So changed it to haproxy and I have listener.logz.io:5015 as the backend.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The problem was 'listener.logz.io:5015' expects a certificate. Added ssl option to pass certificate, but in order for haproxy to identify the certificate, I had to change the hostname to **something.logz.io**. So I had changed the hostname where haproxy was installed to **proxy.logz.io**(I know its a workaround).

The following configurations worked:

**filebeat.yml**

```
output:
  logstash:
    hosts: ['proxy.logz.io:5015']
     ssl:
      certificate_authorities:  ['/etc/pki/tls/certs/COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt']
```

**haproxy.cfg**

```
#Forward HAProxy Config

global
 debug
 daemon
 maxconn 10000

defaults
 mode tcp
 timeout client 200000ms
 timeout server 200000ms

#create new frontend to process 5015
frontend https_frontend
  bind *:5015
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  default_backend logz

#Define backend for above frontend
backend logz
  mode tcp
  balance roundrobin
  server logzio listener.logz.io:5015
```